# How to create Xcode project from already existing git cmake project?

Tags: xcode, git, cmake

On macOS, how do I create an Xcode project from existing code? I want to try some features of Xcode like 'profile'.

I currently use Clion for my cmake project, it is also in git repo. I simply want to import it from Xcode but it's not that easy I guess. Here some info about project and IDE:

- It is just a console app written in C++ and cmake project
- It is also on git repo
- Xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a)
- OS El Capitan 10.11.6

Comment: I've been writing cross-compiled code on OSX and Linux for 3 years. I would recommend that you invest a little money - visit the jetbrains.com website and buy a licence for Clion and AppCode. These tools are brilliant. XCode is garbage. It can't even refactor Apple's own language, swift, let alone c++. The Xcode lead was recently fired.
One Clion licence gives you an excellent CMake-based IDE that works on windows, linux and OSX. It even works over XWindows.

Comment: @RichardHodges [AppCode is discontinued as of December 14, 2022](https://blog.jetbrains.com/appcode/2022/12/appcode-2022-3-release-and-end-of-sales-and-support/)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Cmake has a [generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) for Xcode. Try:

```
cmake -G Xcode <dir of CMakeLists.txt>
```

Comment: small remark: all generated content (including Project.xcodeproj) by this command will be created in the folder you'r shell is in. cd to dir of CMakeLists.txt and use `.` as argument...

Comment: @IvanTemchenko or better: `cmake -G Xcode -B build` where `build` is the name of the folder for all generated content

Answer (score -5):

What I do:

"File"->"New"->"Project..."

Select command line tool:

[image]

Fill in some stuff if you'd like:

[image]

Run the dummy project:

[image]

Click on the project file and "Add files to" your project:

[image]

Browse to your pile of source.  Expand the options.  I tend use "added folders" as "Create Groups":

[image]

Go through and prune out the files you don't want:

[image]

Build.  Likely you'll need to keep removing files or adding them till your project works.

Comment: You are basically just ignoring the cmake project. You would have to keep your manually-created xcode project up-to-date with the cmake project everytime something changes in the CmakeLists.txt. That's literally the reason why cmake is used in the first place.