# How can I get all the compile commands from Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I am working on OCLint, and OCLint need all the compile command to do the lint job. now OCLint using xcpretty to parse xcodebuild.log to get the compile commands. So, I have to build the project even I only want to lint few source files. I wonder is there anyway to get the compile commands other than parse the xcodebuild.log?

Comment: I think there is no suitable other way. But you can think about _reverting your problem_: You can use `cmake` which can create Xcode projects Cmakefiles. BTW. Xcode has a great builtin analyzer. Why are you not using it?

Comment: @macmoonshine Thank you very much, I don't familiar with `cmake`, could you be more specific, how I achieve this. And does Xcode buildin analyzer support analyze parts of all source files?

Comment: I'm not so familiar with `cmake` ;), but you can create Xcode projects easily (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829852/how-to-create-xcode-project-from-already-existing-git-cmake-project). You can run the Xcode analyzer with _Product -> Analyze_, or _Shift-Command-B_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it is to write a wrapper for `clang` and linkers.

Using this answer: [How can I force Xcode to use a custom compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43355809/598057) you can redirect Xcode to compile your code with your own "clang" which might be a python shell script. This script would just grab a command passed to it and dump it to some file.

One detail though: if you use custom `CC` Xcode will also try to use it for linking C/C++ files this is why your script has to do nothing if it is called in a linker mode.

I have used this technique for another task: compiling my whole project with `-emit-llvm` flag to get all my code as LLVM bitcode. The example of a similar Python script can be found [here](https://github.com/mull-project/mull-auto-test/blob/f1b3e5414ec96add5662dfef1d93b91178cc8517/mull-clang).

Start by writing "hello world" script. Tell Xcode use it as `CC`, run your project and see the "hello world" string in your build log. From there you will know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I just use the -dry-run and regexpr to filter the compile commands. The -dry-run said, 

`-dry-run    do everything except actually running the commands`

The performance is just ok.
And it will be great if xcode provide one. They will be the only who can do this, and I think it is pretty usefull.