# When trying to generate an Xcode project from a cmake folder, I get an error related to Xcode new build system

Tags: xcode, cmake

I am trying to generate an Xcode project from a cmake folder, using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41830798/942165) very good answer. When executing this command:

```
cmake -G Xcode <dir of CMakeLists.txt>
```

I get:

```
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  The custom command generating

    /Users/fofo/Developer/ClientProject/desktop/always_build

  is attached to multiple targets:

    rake-all
    stage

  but none of these is a common dependency of the other(s).  This is not
  allowed by the Xcode "new build system".


CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
```

Can I somehow specify to `cmake -G Xcode <dir of CMakeLists.txt>` to use the old Xcode build system, or can I somehow solve the problem changing the cmake files?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have found the answer [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/Xcode.html#xcode-build-system-selection). It is possible to use the legacy build system using:

```
cmake -G Xcode -T buildsystem=1 .
```

Comment: Xcode 14 drops support for the old build system, so this solution will stop working as Xcode 14 is adopted.

Answer (score 0):

This fix still works in XCode 14.3.1 so I'm not sure when they'll drop support for the old build system...

Comment: They've (finally ?) dropped support in 15.x; maybe XCode support in CMake was improved, because for my case (building VTK) it now actually works in the "new" buildsystem without problems.